# Offset points in space with python

Tags: python, geometry, vector

I have a path-curve that uses a profile with two circles (`reference` and `profile` on the image below). I'd like to create a second curve at the same distance as the distance between the profile circles (red arrow between the `profile` circles) — a black curve in the `expected result`. If I simply offset each point of a curve by that distance, my curve is 'parallel' to the original (`my result`), how do I calculate those vectors that are used for offset?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95289/distance-between-two-bezier-curves/95299#95299

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you for your input, forgot to mention that I use polygon splines here, not bezier curves: all the roundness comes from a bunch of points, so mathematically this should be possible. I know how to do that in 2d, but not in 3d :/

Comment: https://blendermarket.com/products/curve-offset-in-3d-space

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you for all the links but I'm looking for a python solution for polygon splines: `curves offset` is a paid addon that works only on bezier curves

Comment: I am not a Python expert, but it would seem that you would have to iterate through point by point and get the vector between points to go the direction you want. I hope to see the solution!

Comment: @CobyRandal my question is exactly how do I find this vector :). I've tried several ways I could think of but I'm bad with math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect (but imperfections are like the one we have bevelling or insetting, etc. too far), and that can also be the case with a curve and bevel object.

The principle:

- Start with the first two vertices of the curve, a segment S0 = (V0, V1)
- Get the location of the starting position of the // curve P0
- Calculate the displacement D0 = (V0, P0)
- Calculate the normal N0 = D0 cross (V0, V1)

Now iterate for 1 to n:

- Get the new normal by D(i-1) cross S(i)
- Get the new D(i) = S(i) cross N(i)
- The location is Pi = Vi + Di

Result with imperfection (the active curve with 4 empties as starting points):

[image]

Main part of the code is the following (complete code is in the blend file below, so this snippet won't work alone).

To use it from the blend file: the curve is the active object, starting points are selected object.

```
def create_parallel(curve_object, from_object):
    #Get the poly spline
    poly = curve_object.data.splines[0]

    #Create the target poly spline
    target_object = create_curve(curve_object, bpy.context.scene.collection)
    target_poly = target_object.data.splines[0]

    #Get the starting location in curve coordinates
    starting_location = curve_object.matrix_world.inverted() @ from_object.location

    #Delta from the first point
    delta = starting_location - poly.points[0].co.xyz
    #Its length
    distance = delta.length
    #Keep it normalized
    delta.normalize()
    #Orthogonal direction
    ortho = delta.cross( poly.points[1].co.xyz - poly.points[0].co.xyz ).normalized()

    #First vertex
    target_poly.points[0].co = (*starting_location, poly.points[0].co.w)

    for i in range(len(poly.points)-1):
        prev = poly.points[i].co
        co = poly.points[i+1].co

        axis = (co.xyz - prev.xyz)

        #Orthogonal direction is recalculated to be orthogonal to this delta and the next curve segment
        ortho = delta.cross(axis).normalized()

        #New delta is calculated as being orthogonal to the curve orientation and the current orthogonal direction
        delta = (axis).cross( ortho ).normalized()

        #Calculate the location of the current vertex        
        location = co.xyz + delta * distance
        #Assign it to the curve
        target_poly.points[i+1].co = (*location, co.w)
```

[image]

Improving it, should need to relax (or remove) vertices comparing the curvatures of the curves... another story...

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! I went with a different approach (more bruteforce and stupid) but this helped me to understand better the math behind the problem