# Equi-distance of all normals between a shrunken duplicate and its' original

Tags: duplicate

[image]

I am making an oddly shaped box (https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5211186). I want to make some small tablets that slide into the box easily. To do so, I took the ring of inner vertices along the top z plane, duplicated it, and shrunk it along the x and y axis.
--> select all applicable vertices, ctrl+d, s, shift+z. I then extruded the vertices of the new duplicate object along the Z axis to give it 2 mm depth.
The problem with this is that when I do so, the vertices are all different distances from their respective edges. When centered inside the box, I want all vertices of the new small tablet to be 1.5 mm from their closest edge. How can I do so.
See the attached pictures for clarity.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95289/distance-between-two-bezier-curves/

Comment: Rather than scaling, try 'i' "inset faces" operation, which creates vertices then moves them according to their "normal" to the edge (not really their normal, but what you want.)  You can use the operator panel to enter a precise value on the operation.  Inset leaves you your original edges, which you can just delete if you want.  Risk of creating intersection if insetting dense geometry a large distance, which is just kind of an unavoidable fact of life with what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.5)*

In scaling, the displacement is proportional to the distance to the centre/the axis/the plane. So it can not be uniform for general shapes.

Uniform displacement of faces can be achieved with extrusion along normals, checking *Offset Even*:
[image: Uniform extrusion]

Answer (score 2):

You can also enable the addon called *Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools* and then select your edge loop and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Offset Edges > Offset* and tweak the *Width* value in the *Operator Box*.